# Room Database query not returning data, even though there is data in the database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am using this method inside a DAO class to access data from a database:

```
@Query("select * from location_search_results WHERE searchQuery = :query")
fun searchForLocation(query: String): LiveData<LocationSearchResponse>
```

and I am calling it like this:

```
locationResponse = locationResponseDao.searchForLocation(query)
Log.d("db", locationResponse.value.toString())
```

I am then observing the value like this:

```
    fun bindUI() = launch {
        val locationResults = locationViewModel.locationResponse
        val owner = viewLifecycleOwner

        locationResults.observe(owner, Observer {
            if (it == null) return@Observer

            initRecyclerView(it.features.toLocationSearchResultListItem())
        })
    }
```

My problem is that whenever I do this, the observer always returns null, even though there's data in the database that matches the query.  I have also tried it just using `select * from location_search_results` in case it was an issue with the searchQuery parameter, but that also came back null.

Here is what the database looks like:

[image: database]

I'm new to Room and SQLite, so any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `locationResponse.value.` well don't call it like this, use `observe`

Comment: you have to observe the livedata, because at the time Log.d is executed the value of the livedata is still null, that's because the android run the query in a different thread

Comment: I am observing the data later on, where it is still null, sorry I have edited the post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning livedata from room query , it should be observed to get the value.
Something like :
locationResponseDao.searchForLocation(query).observeForever{ response ->
locationResponse.value = response

}

Comment: I am observing it later on, I apologize for the confusion.  I have edited the question with more information to clarify

Comment: No , I mean you need to observe in view model. See my updated answer

Comment: Would that change the fact that it's null?  Why would changing the location of the observer make the data that's returned different?  Legitimately asking, because I have another set of classes that does basically the exact same thing this one does, and it has the observer in the fragment class, and it all works fine

Comment: No , what I said was that  first observe the livedata in view model and update the object. I didn't say to remove the fragment observer code. Basically fragment observer obseves view model livedata which gets updated from view model mutable data